# How to take just the end of files name inside url?

Tags: php

I am working on product import system with icecat.
I have a little problem to resolve with the image.
The problem is Icecat can propose different way to download an image like :

http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/myimage.jpg
http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/medium/myimage.jpg
...
My problem is how to delete this part of element http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/medium/ in this user case to just myimage.jpg

There my current function

```
public function getProductMediumImage() {
  $icecat_products_image_medium = HTML::sanitize($_POST['icecat_products_image_medium']);
  $product_image_medium = str_replace('http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums', '', $icecat_products_image_medium);
  $product_image_medium = str_replace('http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/medium/', '', $icecat_products_image_medium);


  if (!is_null($icecat_products_image_medium)) {
    $content = @file_get_contents($icecat_products_image_medium);
    file_put_contents($this->template->getDirectoryPathTemplateShopImages() . 'products/' . $product_image_medium, $content);
  }

  $product_image = 'products/' . $product_image_medium;

  return $product_image;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One and easiest way is to use **basename()** function:

```
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/myimage.jpg';
echo basename($url); // echoes myimage.jpg
```

You could also use **pathinfo()** which returns array one of which items is basename:

```
Array (
    [dirname] => http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums 
    [basename] => myimage.jpg 
    [extension] => jpg 
    [filename] => myimage
)
```

And to get basename from there you do:

```
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/myimage.jpg';
$img = pathinfo($url)['basename'];
echo $img; // echoes myimgage.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function to get information of a file system path. This will also work for a url.

```
$_POST['icecat_products_image_medium'] = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/myimage.jpg';
$url = HTML::sanitize($_POST['icecat_products_image_medium']);
$info = pathinfo($url);
echo $info['basename']; // 'myimage.jpg'
var_export($info); //array (
//  'dirname' => 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums',
//  'basename' => 'myimage.jpg',
//  'extension' => 'jpg',
//  'filename' => 'myimage'
//)
```

Answer (score 1):

[parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) and [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) works wonders

```
$file = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex way:

```
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/whatever.jpg';
preg_match_all('#\/\K(?!.*\/).+$#mui', $url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo $matches[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

strrpos will give the last occurrence of a character, and then you can get the actual image filename.

```
$url = 'http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/myimage.jpg';

echo substr($url, (strrpos ($url, '/') + 1));
```